# WPF Animation Duration

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have a storyboard like the following

Duration="0:0:1" Completed="DeviceExplorer_Completed">

The animation for some reason does not appear to be working linearly.
If I change the duration to something like Duration="0:0:0.8"

and assign the stroyboard to a MouseEnter event of a button, the animation moves but does not complete for some reason, I move my mouse over the button a few times before it enetually completes...

Any ideas why?

Comment: I have been having problems with animations that have durations of less than a second. If I animate the opacity of a control to zero with a duration of 1 second, the control disappears, but with a duration of 0.5 seconds it only half disappears (ie it fades at the same rate as if the duration was 1 second, but only animates for half a second).

Is this a bug? Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue with something like this when I was creating the storyboard and animations dynamically.  What helped me was to ensure that the duration was set on the individual animations.  You might try putting a button on your screen and using that to fire the storyboard... placing a breakpoint there would let you ensure that the animations had the same duration as the storyboard.

After finding the workaround, I haven't had the time to fully debug the issue but I suspect it had to do with the order in which I am creating the storyboard and animations.  In my situation, the storyboard is very dynamic so adjusting the duration on a few extra objects is the least of my concerns.

Answer (score 10):

You have to set the duration on the animation and not the storyboard. The animation will default to a duration of 1 second if not set and the storyboard is ending in less time than that so the animation gets cut short by whatever length of time is the difference.
When you put the duration on the animation it should work fine.