# WPF: Storyboard Trigger inside of ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox` where it's `DataTemplate` is as follows:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Name="modes" ItemsSource="{Binding Modes}" Margin="10,3"/>

        <ComboBox Name="companyName" ItemsSource="{Binding Companies}" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True" Width="0" Margin="10,3">
            <ComboBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=modes}" Value="0" >
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard >
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                 From="0" To="170" Duration="200"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Style>
        </ComboBox>

        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Margin="3"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Margin="3"/>

        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Providers}" Grid.Column="4" IsEditable="True" Margin="10,3"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I want to do is that when I choose the first item in `modes`, `companyName`'s `Width` would expand to 170, but nothing happens when I try this.

Can anyone tell me where is the error in my code?

Comment: Your duration attribute is not specific.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431004/wpf-animation-duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your duration attribute is not specific.

What is 200?

[WPF Animation Duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431004/wpf-animation-duration)